# DevExtreme dxForm nested data datafield not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, devexpress, devextreme

im having a datasource like this :

```
var data = [{
"name" : "jeff",
"house": {
   "size" : "big",
   "color" : "black"
}]
```

and i want the dxForm to be able to do :

```
formElement.dxForm({
  formData: data,
  items:  [{
     dataField : "name"
  },{
     dataField : "house.size"
  }]
 ...
)};
```

i know this should work because it works with basicly all DevExtreme controls...

am i missing something ?

The DevExtreme Questions dont realy answer me, most people kinda figuered it out but on other frameworks and have other problems with it.

Comment: i have created a codepen with the React framework.
val1.val3 works as intended https://codesandbox.io/embed/dxform-with-nested-items-and-formdata-forked-it16e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: what is your target framework now? jquery or react? in your question you are using an array as the `formData`. I think `formData` requires an object not an array. Your react example works for me if i remove line 24.

Comment: Yes, i am working with JQuery, the example was in React to show that it works flawlessly in the React framework.